# Add (already created) partition for /home after OS installation

Tags: partition, fstab, home, move-partition

I made a separate partition for `/home`, but during installation process I forgot to mount it and hence no entry was made in fstab.

I had everything in partition under the root ( well not the swap and efi system partition). I realised what I did, very late and by that time I had already installed packages and wrote data in the home directory.

Now what I want to know is “**is there any way possible to move my home directory to a separate partition with out losing any data?**”

I was thinking of doing something like mounting  the root directory in `/mnt` and than mount a new partition(for home) in `/mnt/home` from a liveUSB and than generate the fstab.

But I am like 79% sure that this will wipe out my home directory.

SPEC: Arch Linux x86_64 latest kernel (5.0.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you already have an home partition, we should be able to do this with out a live OS.

- mount the new home on `/mnt`
- move files from old-home (`/home`), to new home (`/mnt`). (`/home` should now be empty).
- remount new-home to `/home` (bind mount `sudo mkdir -p /home && sudo mount --bind /mnt /home` (you can also use `--move`, in place of `--bind`), or unmount then mount).

It is not as you want, but the mount is not persistent.

- edit `/etc/fstab` (There may be tools to help you with this, I can't remember).

Comment: Will the installed packages turn out fine after this ? Because I have installed package in my home directory. Other files(music ,videos , text files ) will be okay I know , but the I am worried that this may render the environment variables of the software defunct. I am not sure though.

Comment: You need to do the move as root, to ensure that ownership info is not lost. However because it will all end up back in `/home` the environment variable will be OK. Just don't use any of these files **during** he migration.

Comment: what if instead of move , I do copy? just asking. I mean will original files be erased ? or I will end up with two home directory,?

Comment: Did you mean `cp`. If so then the originals will remain, but will be covered by the mount. You can do this, and remove them (or not) latter. You can use a bind mount to mount this part of the root partition on to `/mnt`, when you want to see / remove them.

Comment: I can mount the partition to home but cannot bind mount it. I think bind mount is not possible with partition?

Comment: **or unmount, then mount** (though bind mount should not be a problem)

Comment: i am not familiar with bind mounts . I tried this `mount --bind /path/to/home/partition  /path/to/mountpoint` but it gave an error about the mount ... 'Destination is not directory' . Then I tried without the bind parameters and it mounted. So I made the entry in fstab and rebooted and it works fine... at least for now. Hope it stays that way.

Comment: Was it a directory (preferably empty)?

Comment: no it was not empty. It was the /home directory and all my data is still in it. As i mentioned above , I copied the data from my home directory to the new partition after mounting it on /mnt and than unmounted it and tried to bind mount it to my /home directory.  It didn't work but a generic/simple mount worked and I am using that after editing the fstab . Will there be any problem in future with simple mount? Also , how about the bindfs ? can I use that to bind mount ?

Comment: Ahh I see. You have to choose ① unmount, then mount. or ② bind mount an already mounted directory/file. So in my example `/mnt` has to already have something mounted on it. (you should not need bind mount, so I would stop worrying about it. Except for fun and future).